# Copy a data table column value to another

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, rest, sharepoint

I am trying to copy a jQuery column value to another column. 
I have column name ID and a column named Title.
The title column should contain the value in column ID. 
I am not able to get it done so far.

Here is my code

```
      dataTableExample = $('#mytbl').DataTable({  
        "aaData": data.d.results, 

        "aoColumns": [
        {  
            "mData": "ID"

        }, 
        {  
            "mData": "Title",
            "render":function(mData){
             var a = '<a href=/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID='+"ID"+'>'+mData+'</a>';
             return a;
            }               
        }]
       });
```

this does not work. 
How do I put the value from the ID to the title above?/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change following code

```
"render":function(mData){
         var a = '<a href=/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID='+"ID"+'>'+mData+'</a>';
         return a;
        }
```

to

```
 "render": function ( mdata, type, row ) {
        var a = '<a href=/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID='+row["ID"]+'>'+mData+'</a>';     
      return a }
```

where ID is the column heading or column name

Comment: This works! Please mark it as answer. My question is exactly the same. I show the ID in one column and I have an action column. Inside, I have to have a link with the ID in it.